# phonegap-plugin-push gets an APN token that is not an FCM token

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I'm creating an android/ios application using ionic 1.

## A list of the version.

```
cordova: 7.0.1
ionic: 2.2.2
ios-deploy: 1.9.1 
ios-sim: 6.0.0
node: v8.3.0
```

## A list of the plugins I used.

```
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.7 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.4 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-firebase 0.1.24 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-ignore-lint-translation 0.0.1 "cordova-plugin-ignore-lint-translation"
cordova-plugin-image-picker 1.1.1 "ImagePicker"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.5.0 "Diagnostic"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.10.5 "PushPlugin"
```

## Issue

I am implementing push via fcm. Android works fine. However, iOS has an issue. If I check my DB, android phones will get the fcm tokens normally, but ios seems to get APN tokens. like below

```
device_id: F62304A7-19EC-49D9-BFC8-922D254D3DFA
registration_id : 0876b8eb6a6e1eb525e164ced4552bcd881d2e219b13f89ff1f4472c9d69695e
```

Has anyone solved the same problem with you?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue.

I added the following code to config.xml.

Then I can get the FCM token normally.

```
<platform name="ios">
  <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
</platform>
```